# How to iterate through a ListView in UWP?

Tags: c#, loops, listview, uwp

I have a ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvVorlagen">
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
     </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

I add some Items to it:

```
lvVorlagen.Items.Add("A");
lvVorlagen.Items.Add("B");
lvVorlagen.Items.Add("C");
lvVorlagen.Items.Add("D");
```

How can i iterate through the Items and check if they are check or check them programmatically? I was used to things like

```
foreach (ListViewItem bla in this.lvVorlagen.Items)
{
  if (bla.IsSelected)
  {
    tbMail.Text = "ASD";
  }
}
```

But then i get:

> System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem'."

Next try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.lvVorlagen.Items.Count; i++)
{
  if (this.lvVorlagen.Items[i].IsSelected)
  {
    tbMail.Text = "ASD";
  }
}
```

But then, i only have `Equals`, `ToString`, etc at `this.lvVorlagen.Items[i]`.

I read a lot about binding, but i don't know how i can bind the items with the possibility to select.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ContainerFromItem` method to get a reference to the `ListViewItem` container for a specific item:

```
foreach (object item in this.lvVorlagen.Items)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = this.lvVorlagen.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null && lvi.IsSelected)
    {
        tbMail.Text = "ASD";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mm8  will allow you to iterate through the ListItems.  Another approach is to use data binding using an ObservableCollection.  This will simplify iteration because you do not iterate through the list items, you iterate through the collection bound to the ListView.  To select simply look at MainList.SelectedItem it will evaluate to the object type (in this case a string).  I also added an example of how to change the value.  You can use LINQ expression on the ObservableCollection to achieve sorting.

XAML

```
    <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="15">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="lvVorlagen"
              Margin="0,0,0,15"
              Foreground="Black"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind LvVorlagen, Mode=OneWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="btnIterate" 
            Content="Iterate" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Height="40" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Background="Orange"
            Foreground="Black"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Click="BtnIterate_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSelect" 
            Content="Select" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Height="40" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Background="LightBlue"
            Foreground="Black"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Click="BtnSelect_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnChange" 
            Content="Change" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Height="40" 
            FontSize="18" 
            Background="LightGreen"
            Foreground="Black"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Click="BtnChange_Click"/> 
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        LvVorlagen = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LvVorlagen.Add("A");
        LvVorlagen.Add("B");
        LvVorlagen.Add("C");
        LvVorlagen.Add("D");


    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> LvVorlagen
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void BtnIterate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string value in LvVorlagen)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Select Item is: " + MainList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No items are selected.");
        }
    }
    private void BtnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = MainList.SelectedIndex;
        LvVorlagen[selectedIndex] = "X";
    }
}
```